# ActionScript 3 - Inline import?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, inline, import

I'm a strong Java developer, and I've been learning Flash for the last 16 hours.

However, I've come across one thing that keeps bugging me.
Why is it, that I can't do something similar to,

```
try {  } catch(e:flash.errors.IOError) { trace(e); }
```

Instead of having to specify an actual `import flash.errors.IOError` statement?
Is there any way to do inline imports?

Also, is there a technical name for "inline imports"? I just made that up..

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean to use the "fully qualified name" to avoid using an import statement.

Comment: You're certain your first example doesn't work? I was always under the impression you could declare data-types by their full qualifying class name. Is it because it's being declared in a try {} catch {} clause?

Comment: And people say AS3 is dying, huh? For what it's worth, if you're a Java dev you probably don't think about the time implications of lots of try...catches. If you're an ActionScript dev, often you do, and you try to avoid them like the plague! Also, unlike Java you can't specify what a method throws, so they're not really as useful either.

Answer (score 3):

Fully qualified names are serving only to resolve naming conflicts. To use class, import directive is mandatory (unlike C#, where fully qualified name will do.) See language documentation, [import keyword](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#import) section:

> if you want to use the
>   flash.display.Sprite class in a
>   script, you must import it. This
>   requirement is different from previous
>   versions of ActionScript, in which the
>   import directive was optional.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid those import statements. But you don't actually have to type them yourself: if you use Flash Builder, you can use its autocomplete functionality to automatically create those import statements for you. And it also has an "organize imports" command which will remove unused imports for you.

Comment: I'm using the FlashDevelop IDE, and I don't mind doing them myself I was just hoping I could keep one-time imports out of the main import block.

Comment: Why would it help to keep one-time imports out of the import block?